# javascript only works in <script> tags, not js file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a clickable dropdown menu. But when I run the javascript in its own js file the js doesn't work. However, when I put the javascript in  tags in my html document, the menu works perfectly fine. Does anyone know how to make the javascript work in its own js file?

```
function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: html code? you should call that javascript after your html is processed. `body onload="init();"` or similar would due the trick.

Comment: The issue is probably how you are including the script in your file - can you include the html where your <script> tag references the javascript file?

Comment: What is the error when it does not run?

Comment: @Daniek you assume much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // do stuff here

}, false);
```

Comment: where do you want me to put this?

Comment: paste your js into where it says `do stuff here`

Comment: add a line to your js `console.log('I just ran');`.  Open your web developer tools console.  If you don't see I just ran, your js ain't firing.  You can put a console.log anywhere for debugging purposes.  Good luck.

Comment: I just ran it in chrome. It shows the whole line. So when I open it up it shows "console.log('I just ran');"

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a JS file called script.js and then add this to HTML document before closing body tag:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

I assume you are not including the script correctly. Check your console for errors.

Also, if you are including script in the head section, it could be loaded before the HTML, therefore the selectors possibly could not be found. Including script at the end of the HTML document (before closing body tag) would assure the document is loaded before script is executed.

Comment: I named my js document something else but I do have that

Comment: check if script is accessible through browser. Get the URL of the script, and make sure it renders when you try to call it from the browser.

Comment: In Firefox, click on F12, then click on Network tag to see if your script is being rendered with code 200.

Comment: Do you want me top open the script in my browser? When I do it's just a blank page

Comment: That's your problem. Perhaps you have duplicate script located in other directory. Check your FTP for directory and file location.

Comment: Um I don't really use firefox, so bare with me. I opened the network tag, but i don't see any numbers.

Comment: I don't think I have a duplicate script, I made the script, then mut the code right in.

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute JavaScript from an external file, you will need to include the file in the HTML file using something like the following:

```
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="location/of/file/filename.js"></script>
</head>
```

From there, make the HTML element you are using call the JavaScript function you are wishing to execute.

Example:

```
<button onclick="functionName()">Click!</button>
```

This will then go to the function you are calling in the JavaScript file and execute the body of the function.