# localStorage Javascript code works in HTML file but not in Javascript file, I have tried many StackOverflow solutions

Tags: javascript, html, dom, firefox, local-storage

I'm trying to use basic localStorage methods. They work perfectly fine in HTML, but do not work in a stand-alone Javascript file.

HTML Code (Works):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Javascript</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Our first page">
        <meta name="keywords" content="html tutorial template">

        <script>
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
            localStorage.setItem("Name", "Jeff");
            console.log(localStorage.getItem("Name"));
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Content goes here.
    </body>
</html>
```

JS Code (Doesn't Work):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    localStorage.setItem("Name", "Jeff");
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("Name"));
});
```

or

```
document.addEventListener("load", function() {
    localStorage.setItem("Name", "Jeff");
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("Name"));
});
```

or

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    localStorage.setItem("Name", "Jeff");
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("Name"));
}, false);
```

or

```
window.onload = function() {
    localStorage.setItem("Name", "Jeff");
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("Name"));
}
```

Here are the solutions I have tried:

[Using `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {});`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51309305/getelementbyid-work-in-html-file-but-not-in-js-file)

[Using `document.addEventListener("load", function() {});`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57641159/script-tag-works-in-html-file-but-not-external-js-file)

[Using `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {}, false);`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41412475/javascript-only-works-in-script-tags-not-js-file)

[Using `window.onload = function() {}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57496304/javascript-works-in-html-file-but-not-in-javascript-file)

[Using `window.onload = function() {}` (again)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72676073/js-doesnt-completely-work-in-a-js-file-but-works-in-a-html-file-with-the-scri)

[Using `window.onload = function() {}` (again...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498482/javascript-cant-find-element-by-id)

I still end up with the same result when running the js file: Nothing happens in localStorage, and I see nothing in the console.

I'm not sure where to go from here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you trying to run the JS after moving it to a file of its own?

Comment: Where and how is this internal JavaScript referred in your HTML then?

Comment: @Quentin Locally by opening the js file in Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: @CBroe I am not trying to refer to the js in HTML, I just want the js code to work independently of HTML. The two commands seen in the js code (.setItem() and .getItem()) work in the console, but not if I load them from a js file.

Comment: By "referring to", I meant _how_ you embedded your external JavaScript file _into_ your HTML page. Which, seeing the accepted answer now, it appears you did not do in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web browsers only execute JavaScript in the context of an HTML document where it is loaded with a `<script>` element (a `src` attribute allows a script to be loaded from a URL instead of being embedded in the HTML document).

(Let’s ignore browser extensions, pasting things into the developer tools, and bookmarklets as they aren’t relevant here).

Just entering a URL to a JavaScript program will cause its source code to be displayed in the main viewport. It won’t execute the code. There is no way to make it execute the code outside of an HTML document.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I did not understand that an HTML document is required to run JavaScript code in a web browser.